# Two projects use the same Postgres database, and the project on Django

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have two projects that use the same Postgresql database. One of these projects is written with Golange and the other with Django. I have a task in the Django project, to take the data from the table that is created in another project. More precisely I have to take the data from the Clients table, which is not created in Django. There is no information about Clients table on the Django project.

Below is how I take the date from the Cook table, which is created in the Django project.

[image]

How can I take the date from the Clients table in the same way as above?

Below are both project repositories, and some screenshots from the database.

https://github.com/NarminSH/Go-Client.git

https://github.com/NarminSH/Lezzetly

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

- Use [Django's raw SQL queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly) to just `SELECT` data from that table
- Use [`inspectdb`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/legacy-databases/#auto-generate-the-models) to have Django generate a model for the `clients` table. The model will have `Meta.managed` set to False, so Django won't touch it (e.g. do migrations). You can then use regular Django ORM operations for it.
- Manually write the model, setting `db_table = "clients"` and `managed = False` on the Meta class. You can then use regular Django ORM operations for it.

The model Django (or you) might generate could look something like

```
class Client(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    # ... etc ...

    class Meta:
       managed = False
       db_table = 'clients'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You help me save a lot of my time. I manually wrote a model as you show and works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Create Django models based on the database structure by introspecting an it with [inspectdb](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/django-admin/#inspectdb) command:

```
$ python manage.py inspectdb > models.py
```

Then you can query the database with Django API.

Have a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/legacy-databases/#auto-generate-the-models